# JavaFX TableView how to get cell's data?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm using that method to get whole object.

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
```

How can I get data from single cell?
[image]

I mean like get **S20BJ9DZ300266** as String?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you know something is selected, you can do

```
TablePosition pos = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
int row = pos.getRow();

// Item here is the table view type:
Item item = table.getItems().get(row);

TableColumn col = pos.getTableColumn();

// this gives the value in the selected cell:
String data = (String) col.getCellObservableValue(item).getValue();
```

Comment: Awesome saved me.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you haven't selected any row but know where and what you want....

```
// Item here is the table view type:
    Unpaid item = userTable.getItems().get(0);

    TableColumn col = userTable.getColumns().get(3);

    // this gives the value in the selected cell:
    String data = (String) col.getCellObservableValue(item).getValue();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == null) {
                selected.setText("");
                return;
            }
                       System.out.println(newValue.getId());
        });
```

NB: "getId" is your "get" Column and "table" is the name of your tabelview

Comment: the not only post code, try to explain what was wrong and how this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I get the string, for example, "[1, proveedor1, calzado1, Rojo, 39, 600, 2, 1200]", and get the frist cell (id) whit substring. saludos

```
TablePosition pos = (TablePosition) tableVenta.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
int index = pos.getRow();
String selected = tableVenta.getItems().get(index).toString();
selected = selected.substring(1, selected.indexOf(","));
System.out.println(selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scene builder, add a method to On Edit Commit for the particular column and add the logic in the controller class. Use `event.getNewValue()` to get the new value entered by the user. Eg.

```
@FXML
private void UpdateName(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<ModelClass, String> event) {
    ModelClass mc = Table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    mc.setName(event.getNewValue());
    System.err.println("new value "+event.getNewValue());
}
```

Use this when you allow editable columns

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code i think it's working

```
String a=personTable.getColumns().get(0).getCellObservableValue(0).getValue().toString(); 
System.out.println("value"+a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like this to add data to table:

```
ObservableList<Artikl> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
data.add(new Artikl("Some String data"));
```

Artikl is class of setters and getters.

```
public class Artikl {
private String KAT;
public Artikl(String kb)
{
   this.KAT=kb;
}

public String getKAT()
{
    return KAT;
}
public void setKAT(String kb)
{
    KAT=kb;
}
}
```

And to get it back I'm using:

```
ObservableList<Artikl> data = tableName.getItems();
for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
{
System.out.println(data.get(i).getKAT());
}
```

This prints it all. To get selected item:

```
System.out.println(data.get(tableName.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).getKAT());
```