# JavaFX FXML : Select and get values from multiple cells of TableView

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

Is it possible to choose individual cells only and not entire row from the tableview? Multiple cell selection can be done on the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in FXML directly, but you can do so in your controller:

```
// allow selection of individual cells (instead of entire rows):
tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

// allow selection of multiple cells at once:
tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

To get the selected cell values you can follow [JavaFX TableView how to get cell's data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090583/javafx-tableview-how-to-get-cells-data)