# How to get Values from the JFX Table

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8

I need to get all values from JFX Table View. Tell me to way for that. it's very important to me. below has that table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all items in the TableView you can use the [getItems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getItems--) method. Otherwise if you want [only the selected data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090583/javafx-tableview-how-to-get-cells-data), you can use a [SelectionModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getSelectionModel--) to get the selected item.